# How to imitate actions with the mouse thumb moved left or right in tests in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, events, jestjs

I create a view where user is be able to modify layout split according to his needs using mouse thumb moved left or right. I am trying to perform tests for this.

I tried to initiate the event with

dispatchEvent

or

fireEvent

I use library from https://split.js.org/ where the gutter is added automatically.

This is my code:

```
   const initialSize = 50;
    const regex = /^calc\((\d{1,3})%.+$/;
    const getPercentageFromCalc = (w: string) => {
      const matches = regex.exec(w) as RegExpExecArray;
      return matches[1];
    };

    it("using mouse thumb moved left", async () => {
      const initialLeftWidth = leftContainer.style.width;
      const initialLeftWidthValue = getPercentageFromCalc(initialLeftWidth);
      expect(initialLeftWidthValue).toEqual(initialSize.toString());

      const initialRightWidth = rightContainer.style.width;
      const initialRightWidthValue = getPercentageFromCalc(initialRightWidth);
      expect(initialRightWidthValue).toEqual(initialSize.toString());

      const resizer = template?.shadowRoot?.querySelector(".gutter");

      fireEvent.mouseDown(resizer);
      fireEvent.mouseMove(resizer, { clientX: -400 });
      fireEvent.mouseUp(resizer);

      expect(Number(initialLeftWidthValue)).toBeLessThan(initialSize);
      expect(Number(initialRightWidthValue)).toBeGreaterThan(initialSize);
    });
```

but I get:

```
Expected: < 50
    Received:   50
```

Is there any way to initiate a mouse movement like the one on the https://split.js.org/ ?

Answer (score -1):

import { mount } from 'enzyme';

page = ;
page Mounted = mount(page);

cons t button = page Mounted. find('#some _button');
expect(button. length).to Be(1); // It finds it alright
button.simulate('click'); // Nothing happens

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Some friendly suggestions: encompass your code blocks in "\`\`\`" or "\`" for one liners, and try to explain what your solution is to the problem instead of posting code.